# Error with installing and importing gTTS in Python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, gtts

I'm facing this issue whenever I am installing and importing gTTS.
Issue in installing:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\gtts-cli.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\gtts-cli.exe.deleteme'
```

Issue in importing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/check.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gtts import gTTS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts'
```

I did `pip install gtts`
and imported `from gtts import gTTS`.

Thank you!

> PS: Python version : `3.10.0`

Comment: Maybe the module to install is not called gtts, Try somehow else.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to install gTTS in Python.

There can be problems caused in installation and usage because of Admin access. The solution is to install gTTS using :
`pip install -U gtts`

---

Reference: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9023#issuecomment-713171229